# functional analysis question: extended version of completion of $L_2$ space

Tags: functional-analysis

In $L_2$ space, only use domain [0, 1].  Prove, for any $C^2$ function F in $L_2$, there exits a sequence of polynomials ($f_k$) such that $f^{(r)}_k$ tends to $F^{(r)}$ for r=0,1,2 uniformly. 
Note: $f^{(r)}_k$ means the $r^{th}$ derivative of $f_k$.

Comment: To everybody: please do refrain from trying to edit somebody else's question to ask one of your own!

Comment: What do you mean by a function $F$ $C^2$ in $L_2$? If $f$ is $C^2$, by Stone-Weierstrass, a sequence of polynomial converges uniformly on $[0,1]$ to $f''$. We can use this sequence to get an approximation of $f'$ and $f$.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  It is right.  I confused myself before.